# One-Page-Checkout registration leads to an empty cart in CHROME (purchase and registration are successful)

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, onepage-checkout, register, chrome-browser

Basically what it says in the title. If a guest chooses to register during the one-page checkout, when he clicks the final purchase button he gets redirected to an empty cart page instead of the success page ONLY when using Chrome. Everything works fine in Firefox and IE.

The purchase and the registration are still successful though, both the registration E-Mail and the purchase E-Mail are being sent.

Comment: Could be a form key issue, which version of magento are you using?  Magento added a bunch of form keys in 1.9.2.3. Try adding the following:

`<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />` 

below the opening 

`<div class="fieldset">` 

tag in `persistent/customer/form/register.phtml`

Comment: Yeah, I updated to 1.9.2.3, but I've already added the form keys everywhere needed. As stated, it all works, registration works, the purchase works, it just redirects Chrome-users (and only those) to the empty cart instead of the success page.

I tried adding yours anyways, didn't notice any changes.

Comment: Have you had a look in the logs? Anything further to point you in the right direction? Check `var/log/system.log` & `var/log/exception.log` if there is anything that relates in there please update your question with the entry.

Comment: Yup, nothing there... That's why I'm perplexed (I left the logs running from when I was fixing a different problem a while ago).

Comment: Ok, so this looks to definitely be a deeper issue, possibly an issue with the server set up, how its handling your sessions. Can you check your server logs? Maybe there is something there which could help.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't access those, the webhoster is a bit weird. What is strange to me is, that it is an issue limited to Google Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same cookie issue... I fixed it as follows:

go to "System > Configuration > Web > Session Cookie Management" and enter domainname.com in "Cookie Domain" & "Cookie path" /

Comment: Tried it, doesn't work unfortunately. The only difference it made was, that it also kept the new registration logged out, instead of automatically logging it in.

Comment: Clear you browser cache and admin cache in folder /var/cache

Comment: Done and done, still doesn't work.

Comment: I think I had done it wrong, I tried it again today and it works, thanks mate!

Comment: Cool ... Happy to hear it...